# How do I create a Makefile for building an 64 bit Operating System for Raspberry Pi 4B's ARM architecture?

Tags: makefile, operating-system, arm64, raspberry-pi4

How do I create a Makefile for building an 64 bit Operating System for Raspberry Pi 4B's ARM architecture?

This is what I have so far, am I on the wrong track?

I don't know what values to assign to GPPPARAMS or LDPARAMS to have the correct "mode". I have taken some Assembler in college but I have noticed it much varies from architecture to architecture and various different coding conventions.

```
GPPPARAMS = -march=??? -mcpu=??? etc???
ASPARAMS = ???
LDPARAMS = -EL and ???

objects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp
        g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
        as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
        ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
        sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

Comment: I don't see how we can answer the question in this form.  This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. We handle specific, narrowly scoped questions here.  It seems like one thing you're interested in is what compiler and linker options to use for your purposes, which is a lot closer to the kind of question we answer here.  Focusing on that and pairing it with the clearest idea you can muster of what exactly your purposes are would probably make this the sort of thing we're looking for.

Comment: Side note: you might want to search around about the differences between a "hosted" and a "freestanding" C implementation.  You're likely most familiar with the former, but the latter is what you need for something that runs on bare metal, such as an OS kernel.